# Number of instructions in JVM

Tags: jvm, bytecode

I was asked the following question in an exam today. I still don't know the answer.

Java uses stack for byte code in JVM. Each instruction is of one byte, so how many such instructions (per byte code) are possible in an operating system.

All I know is that the stack is 32 bits wide. Can anybody help me (I am a beginner in JVM)?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the stack, or operating systems, or the JVM. The only relevant word is 'byte'.

Comment: Is the answer "4 instructions" then?

Comment: The answer has to do with how many distinct values can be held in a bye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected answer was almost certainly 256, because there are 256 possible values of a byte.

This of course has nothing to do with the actual JVM instruction set. The number of possible instructions can vary anywhere from a couple dozen to an exponentially large number depending on how you count.

The actual JVM instruction set has many unused opcodes, one opcode that conceptually represent more than one instruction, and many instructions that can be encoded in tons of different ways with multiple different opcodes. Many instructions are more than one byte, with a couple that can be up to 64kb long. And that isn't even getting into stuff like how you count the wide prefix.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "many instructions are more than one byte, with a couple that can be up to 64kb long". The OP is obviously talking about the number of different opcodes that are recognised. And the spec is quite explicit about how wide should be interpreted.